# How can you rewrite my code to solve my task?

Tags: python

#### The assignment

> Three candidates participated in the election of the Chief. The first candidate received N1 votes, the second candidate received N2 votes, and the third candidate received N3 votes. For each candidate solve the following problem: how many votes should be added to this candidate to win the election?
>
> Winning the election means that the number of votes for this candidate was strictly greater than the number of votes for any other candidate. Note that you must solve this problem independently for each candidate, i.e., adding votes for any candidate does not affect the calculations when analyzing the answer for the other two candidates.
>
> #### Input data format
>
> Your program is given three non-negative integers 1, 2 and 3. All numbers do not exceed 100.
>
> #### Output data format
>
> Print three numbers of the minimum number of additional and required votes for each candidate.

The ex. (input: 10 10 10; output 1 1 1) ; (input: 10 20 5; output 11 0 16)

My code works nearly correctly, but it passes only 19/21 tests for some reason:

```
n1, n2, n3 = map(int, input().split())

max_votes = max(n1, n2, n3)

required_votes1 = max(max_votes - n1 + 1, 0)
required_votes2 = max(max_votes - n2 + 1, 0)
required_votes3 = max(max_votes - n3 + 1, 0)

# Check if the candidate already has the maximum votes, in which case, they need 0 additional votes to win.
if n1 == max_votes:
    required_votes1 = 0
if n2 == max_votes:
    required_votes2 = 0
if n3 == max_votes:
    required_votes3 = 0

print(required_votes1, required_votes2, required_votes3)
```

[image]

Comment: @deceze Why close the question? I thought the OP made a fairly honest attempt at the clearly given question. While it is unclear which tests exactly failed, it isn't hard to see what they are given the simplicity of the question.

Comment: @blhsing There is indeed no specific error description here that is of use to anyone in the future. "Here's a task description, here's my code, find the problem" is not a good question.

Comment: When copy-pasting a homework assignment, ***please*** at least format it properly (it was one big wall of text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't consider the situation n1==n2==n3. Your code will output "0 0 0" in this situation, but the correct answer is "1 1 1". When you are doing homework, you need pass all example cases before you hand it to your teacher.

- Correct code:

```
    def test():
       n1, n2, n3 = map(int, input().split())
       max_votes = max(n1, n2, n3)
       required_votes1 = max(max_votes - n1 + 1, 0)
       required_votes2 = max(max_votes - n2 + 1, 0)
       required_votes3 = max(max_votes - n3 + 1, 0)
       if n1 == max_votes and n2!= max_votes and n3!= max_votes:
           required_votes1 = 0
       if n2 == max_votes and n1!= max_votes and n3!= max_votes:
           required_votes2 = 0
       if n3 == max_votes and n1!= max_votes and n2!= max_votes:
           required_votes3 = 0
       print(required_votes1, required_votes2, required_votes3)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. That has worked. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Simpler](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3p-QZ6ijkGQGxsYKtQm5igUZmXomOQmZeQWmJhqZecUFOJpDW5CooAoprcCkAQW5ihQYIQ3RpKugq5BkqaCsAzTHQ1EFVYQhXYYRHhRFYhTFMBZcmxG1QJy5YbmigYGSgYArhAgA) with the max of the *others* instead of the max of *all*.

Comment: @KellyBundy [Generalized](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3a8vyS1KLFWwVcjKLSzRyEws0MvNKdBQy8wpKSzQ09YoLcjKBtKYmV0ERUEJDC6ikAozB-qKtMmMVtBUg7Ewgy9AqVlNBV6EMxNRRMNBUSMsvUsjUAQpk5imk5pXmphYllqRCNANNhTgC6pYFyw0NFIwMFEwhXAA) with a list.

Comment: @blhsing I had considered doing that, but decided it might be bad advice, due to the unnecessary quadratic runtime If you actually do have an arbitrarily long list.

Comment: @KellyBundy Quadratic runtime, yes, but unnecessary? I can't quite come up with a better performing algorithm, so it might just be necessary (until your magic proves otherwise as usual ;-D).

Comment: @KellyBundy Oops spoke too soon. Here's an *O(n)* [generalization](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY49CsJAEEb7nOIrZzWRGBBEksOkSMxCdnfcTBa8hq1NGvVM3saRiFPMzxt4fPcnX2UIflkes_TF8X3rY3AYupYvsI5DFPixjedukixzOTyaP6AqRwrSTTg1GK0C1zJZLzms51nI7CYerU6tjKN-aEPksAUl1HAI8StsdNOWjEGBhF5pUsPqNmZN9gu4vPYlqhKH9fwA). You're right indeed that a quadratic runtime is unnecessary.

Comment: @blhsing [Another](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5LCsJAEET3c4padqsJiSC4UO8SxOBA5kPmg-JR3MxGPZO3scm46npQr6nn29_j1dlSXimOzf77yC5eAo6YdIhkBk_axg209SkSt8FPWi6zMtIxw42WPisruMT27JIVk5WfRaUVGaxBGQcYuBkWJ_SMBhmjYJbXVWSuE_5LyqfvsO2wq_gD). And you can simplify your `v < m or n == m == v` to `v < m or n == m`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah yes `== v` was totally unnecessary. Your `list.count` is much simpler too. Your `n > 1` test can be moved outside the generator expression as a slight optimization, as is the usual [abuse](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BCsIwEEX3nuIvJ2pLKwgi1rsUsRhoJqGdVD2Lm2zUM3kbR9PZ_PnMf_x5vMJdLp5Tekbpit3nymhAk5fziH2D3o5Crg1kWdawHKKQKcfQW1Wd8uQja-KXde0tg8bgiHoRBoVoqccViOEHTDjAGRS6dH9rGTOR6-cv0ruusKmwzfYL) of assignment expressions.